# what does " not associated " mean in airodump-ng scan result

Tags: kali-linux, aircrack-ng

airodump-ng wlan0 scan result: 
[image: airodump-ng wlan0 scan result]

In the above image, what does "not associated" mean in client connected section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From airodump-ng documentation [website](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng), description for BSSID field:

> MAC address of the access point. In the Client section, a BSSID of “(not associated)” means that the client is not associated with any AP. In this unassociated state, it is searching for an AP to connect with.